Simulating moving structures of flocks of birds in the sky
Birds can create fascinating moving structures in the sky, as can be seen here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dskCpuxqtI
I wonder how such a time-dependent structure can be simulated in Mathematica.
The structure is the superposition of the trajectories of the individual birds indexed with $i$
$$b(i,t) = \{x(i,t),y(i,t),z(i,t)\}$$
Because there are many birds necesary to create the effect one might think of a hydrodynamical descrition.
An interesting part of the problem is that these birds seem to have a strategy to observe the 7 next neighbours and keep the same distance.
Also there is time delay between cause (position of other birds) and action (of the specific bird in question).
Any ideas and information welcome.

This is too broad to fit within this forum's scope. You are currently requesting help to find an algorithm, rather than a specific question on its implementation. That is, in my opinion, not appropriate for this forum. Once you have an algorithm and an initial attempt at its implementation, of course you are welcome to ask for help on specific aspects of it.

https://medium.com/@adityaananthram/algorithms-in-nature-part-1-e80e80b29719

Simon Woods made something very similar to modeling murmurations. See here

I'd like to express my doubts if closing my question pematurely is a good idea. Actually, it bars potential users here from interesting developements with Mathematica. Thanks to @ydd for saving the topic pointing out a thread of the Wolfram Community as of eleven years ago https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/307243/simulating-moving-structures-of-flocks-of-birds-in-the-sky. Several nice structures have been obtained.

You might take a look at Hoetzlein  You might find some guidance in what is a complex simulation of the mumurations.

@Lexington1776 Thank you very much for the link to the interesting work of Rama Carl Hoetzlein
